# All possible combinations of an array without repeating?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Say I have and array:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
```

How would I go about getting all possible combinations without repeating?

For instance:

```
// "2,1" wouldn't be valid because it's essentially "1,2"

1
1,2
1,2,3
1,2,3,4
2
2,3
2,3,4
3
3,4
4
```

Comment: try some nested loops and come back with what you have. Seeing a solved solution won't help you learn much.

Comment: This isn't "combinations" in the set theory sense, (or permutations), you are looking for all possible subsets, based on your sample output.  (and like the above asked, what have you tried?)

Comment: @DrLivingston: The sample output is subsequences actually, not subsets.

Comment: ah, yeah, good catch.  I didn't look closely enough to notice 1,3 etc. wasn't in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want aren't all possible combinations ([subsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsets), missing are `1,3`, `1,4`, `2,4`), but all [subsequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence). You can get those easily by using two nested loops for start and end of the sequence:

```
function subsequences(arr) {
    var res = [[]];
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        for (var j=i+1; j<=arr.length; j++)
            res.push(arr.slice(i, j));
    return res;
}
```

For all possible subsets - the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15649645/1048572).

Comment: Thanks for the solution and, more importantly, the reference/study material!