# Generate all partitions, defined by one array, with elements of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to find all the partitions of the elements of an array, but with an important variation:

> Each value of the second array needs to be spread out over the values of the first. So all values of the second array are always used.

Given these two arrays:

```
left = [A, B];
right = [1, 2, 3];
```

I expect a collection of the following results:

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = []

A = [1, 2]
B = [3]

A = [1, 3]
B = [2]

A = [2, 3]
B = [1]

A = [1]
B = [2, 3]

A = [2]
B = [1, 3]

A = [3]
B = [1, 2]

A = []
B = [1, 2, 3]
```

Edit:

So just to be clear. This needs to scale for both arrays.

Given arrays:

```
left = [A, B, C, D]
right = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Some of the (many, many possible) results would be:

```
A = [2, 5]
B = [1]
C = []
D = [3, 4, 6]

A = [6]
B = []
C = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
D = []

etc. etc. etc.
```

Comment: Does the order of elements in array matter?

Comment: I don't care about the order. I would prefer if the results were unique (so if there already is A=1,2,3 then A=2,1,3 would be omitted), but even that is not a disaster.

Comment: See if the code here helps [Generating all combinations of an array](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/7001). Or check a library for combinatorics, like this one https://github.com/dankogai/js-combinatorics

Comment: Edit: unfortunately I can't apply this to my problem.

Comment: Is `left` always exactly two arrays? Then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15649645/1048572) should help (just push to `B` when you don't push to `A`)

Comment: *left* can be any length. So if C was added, *right* would need to be spread over 3 arrays instead of 2 giving exponentially more results.

Comment: Yes, but only the essential parts. Even if this is part of SE, we cannot garantee that this post will be there forever.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Solution for any parameter (as long as the result is countable):

**Edit**: This version avoids possible problems with `len = Math.pow(left.length, right.length)` and problems with length over 36 (cnr!).

#### Example:

> `combine(['A', 'B'], [1, 2, 3])` all possible rows are **2^3 = 8**. In this example, the distribution is binary, but it changes the base with more parameters of `left`.

```
  distribution      included in set
i       c            A           B   
----------------------------------------
0     0 0 0     { 1, 2, 3 } {         }
1     0 0 1     { 1, 2    } {       3 }
2     0 1 0     { 1,    3 } {    2    }
3     0 1 1     { 1       } {    2, 3 }
4     1 0 0     {    2, 3 } { 1       }
5     1 0 1     {    2    } { 1,    3 }
6     1 1 0     {       3 } { 1, 2    }
7     1 1 1     {         } { 1, 2, 3 }
```

> The distribution `i = 3` of `0 1 1` evaluates as:
>
> 1. Take the first `0` and take it as index of left `left[0] = A` and move the place value of **0** of right `right[0] = 1` to set A.
> 2. Take the second `1` and take it as index of left `left[1] = B` and move the place value of **1** of right `right[1] = 2` to set B.
> 3. Take the third `1` and take it as index of left `left[1] = B` and move the place value of **2** of right `right[2] = 3` to set B.

#### Another example:

`combine(['A', 'B', 'C'], [1, 2])` all possible rows are 3^2 = 9.

```
  distribution     included in set
i      c          A        B       C
----------------------------------------
0     0 0     { 1, 2 } {      } {      }
1     0 1     { 1    } {    2 } {      }
2     0 2     { 1    } {      } {    2 }
3     1 0     {    2 } { 1    } {      }
4     1 1     {      } { 1, 2 } {      }
5     1 2     {      } { 1    } {    2 }
6     2 0     {    2 } {      } { 1    }
7     2 1     {      } {    2 } { 1    }
8     2 2     {      } {      } { 1, 2 }
```

```js
function combine(left, right) {

    function carry() {
        return c.reduceRight(function (r, _, i, o) {
            return r && !(o[i] = (o[i] + 1) % left.length);
        }, 1);
    }

    var c = Array.apply(null, { length: right.length }).map(function () { return 0; }),
        result = [];

    do {
        result.push(c.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
            r[left[a]].push(right[i]);
            return r;
        }, left.reduce(function (r, a) {
            r[a] = [];
            return r;
        }, {})));
    } while (!carry());
    return result;
}
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = 
    "combine(['A', 'B'], [1, 2, 3]) = " + JSON.stringify(combine(['A', 'B'], [1, 2, 3]), null, 4) + '\n'+
    "combine(['A', 'B', 'C'], [1, 2] = " + JSON.stringify(combine(['A', 'B', 'C'], [1, 2]), null, 4) +'\n'+
    "combine(['A', 'B', 'C'], [1, 2, 3] = " + JSON.stringify(combine(['A', 'B', 'C'], [1, 2, 3]), null, 4) +'\n'+
    "combine(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) = " + JSON.stringify(combine(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), null, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't think this method can be used with a variable length of *left*? I will modify the question to make that more clear.

Comment: Nice answer. Do we need `carry`? Arrays have a maximum length of `2^32-1` anyhow.

Comment: @KingMob, see [older version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31704211/5) of edit, there is a result without carry. the idea was to separate the solution from using `Math.pow(...)`.

Comment: Oh, sure, I was just wondering if there is a need for `carry` given the limits on an array anyway.

Comment: @KingMob, just my personal preference. and the idea not to convert a number to string to an array instead of using an array directly. and you can use length of more than 36. conversion with `Number.toString(base)` is limited to 36 as base.

Comment: Oh I see. I think you can do the base conversion to get the index of the appropriate result array with something like `Math.floor(n / Math.pow(left.length, i)) % left.length` where {0 <= n < len} and {0 <= i < right.length}.

Comment: that is far more simple than `carry()` ..., isn't it?

Comment: Well you'll need `carry` if you're concerned about overflowing integers, but since arrays don't work properly with indexes > 2^32 - 1 I don't think it's a problem. Performance would probably be a limiting factor for large inputs anyway.

Comment: Well you'll need `carry` if you're concerned about overflowing integers, but since arrays don't work properly with indexes > 2^32 - 1 I don't think it's a problem. Performance would probably be a limiting factor for large inputs anyway.

Comment: so what is the point? i can use an integer for counting, but i have to separate it for a needed base. i can use `Number.toString(base)` but only if `base < 37` otherwise this does not work. if i use your mentioned `Math.floor(...)` it does not become more clear, what i am doing, or what you like what i should use. maybe it is easier you write a working example of the solution, you prefer.

Comment: Okay, I've made a version of your answer that uses an integer for counting but works for bases >36. I hope this makes what I was getting at clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I think I came up with one possible solution, but I’m certain it’s far from efficiënt.

Given the arrays:

```
left = [A, B, C]
right = [1, 2, 3]
```

First create a power set of *right*:

```
[]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Then have nested loops through this for each value in *left*. Each loop will check if the value is not already in the previous loop and the last loop will also check if all values are present.

In psuedo this would look something like this:

```
for x in powerset
    a = x
    for y in powerset
        if y not in x
            b = y
            for z in powerset
                if z not in y and z not in x and [x + y + z] = right
                    c = z
                    displayresult
```

**Edit**

Here's this crappy inefficient solution in javascript. Posting it for completion sake.

https://jsfiddle.net/6o03d3L3/

```
function loop(left, right, powerSet, depth, siblings) {
    for (var i=0; i<powerSet.length; i++) {
        var values = powerSet[i];

        var isValueUsed = false;
        for (var k = 0; k < values.length; k++) {
            for (var l = 0; l < siblings.length; l++) {
                for (var m = 0; m < siblings[l].right.length; m++) {
                    if (values[k] === siblings[l].right[m]) {
                        isValueUsed = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (isValueUsed) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isValueUsed) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!isValueUsed) {
            var result = { };
            result.left = left[depth];
            result.right = values;

            var results = siblings.slice();
            results.push(result);

            if (depth < left.length - 1) {
                loop(left, right, powerSet, depth + 1, results);
            } else {
                var valueCount = 0;
                for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                    valueCount += results[j].right.length;
                }

                if (valueCount == right.length) {
                    log(results);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to try and code exactly what you are asking for:

```js
function clone(arr) {
  var copy = new Array(arr.length);
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    copy[i] = new Array();
    for (var j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++)
      copy[i][j] = arr[i][j];
  }

  return copy;
}

function f(left,right){
  var result = [];

  function _f(left,i){
    if (i == right.length){
      result.push(left);
      return;
    }

    for (var j=0; j<left.length; j++){
      var _left = clone(left);
      _left[j].push(right[i]);
      _f(_left,i + 1);
    }
  }

  _f(left,0);
  return result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([[],[]],[1,2,3])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([[],[],[]],[1,2,3])));
```

Output:

```
"[[[1,2,3],[]],[[1,2],[3]],[[1,3],[2]],[[1],[2,3]],[[2,3],[1]],[[2],[1,3]],[[3],[1,2]]
,[[],[1,2,3]]]" 

"[[[1,2,3],[],[]],[[1,2],[3],[]],[[1,2],[],[3]],[[1,3],[2],[]],[[1],[2,3],[]]
,[[1],[2],[3]],[[1,3],[],[2]],[[1],[3],[2]],[[1],[],[2,3]],[[2,3],[1],[]],[[2],[1,3],[]]
,[[2],[1],[3]],[[3],[1,2],[]],[[],[1,2,3],[]],[[],[1,2],[3]],[[3],[1],[2]],[[],[1,3],[2]]
,[[],[1],[2,3]],[[2,3],[],[1]],[[2],[3],[1]],[[2],[],[1,3]],[[3],[2],[1]],[[],[2,3],[1]]
,[[],[2],[1,3]],[[3],[],[1,2]],[[],[3],[1,2]],[[],[],[1,2,3]]]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem can be rephrased like this: generate all possible assignments of labels in *left* to the elements in *right*. This is a standard backtracking problem.

The number of solutions is *l^r* (since you can assign any of the labels to each element, independently), where *l* is the number of elements in *left* and *r* is the number of elements in *right*.

I'll provide a recursive solution, which is maybe you can rewrite in a non-recursive way, though it will not lower the complexity of the algorithm (maybe the constant). There is actually no way to lower the complexity since at some point you need to generate each solution. So do not test it for *l=20* and *r=20*, try smaller numbers :p

```
// sol keeps the labels assigned to the elements in right
public static int[] sol = new int[r];

public static void generate(int p)
{
    for (int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        sol[p] = i;
        if (p==r-1)
        {
            // a solution is ready
            outputSolution(sol);
        }
        else
        {
            // still generating a solution
            generate(p+1);
        }
    }
}

// from where you need the results
generate(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for illustration, this is a version of @NinaScholz's
answer that doesn't use `toString` for base conversion or
implement counting manually. I've kept the structure of the
code the same. `values.length-i-1` could simply be `i', but
I wanted to keep the order of the output the same too.

```js
var combine = function(names, values){
    var result = [],
        max = Math.pow(names.length, values.length),
        m;
    for(m=0; m<max; m+=1){
        result.push(values.reduce(function(buckets, v, i){
            var nidx = Math.floor(m / Math.pow(names.length, values.length-i-1)) % names.length;
            buckets[names[nidx]].push(v);
            return buckets;
        }, names.reduce(function(a,v){
            a[v] = [];
            return a;
        }, {})));
    }
    return result;
};

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(
        combine(Array.apply(null, Array(50)).map(function(_,i){ return i; }), [1,2]),
        null,
        4);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```