# Need to Optimize the function

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm working on this function that has to return all possible values of adding `a` and `b` `n` times for example if `n = 1` then possible values would be `a + a` `a + b` and `b + b`. function below works but it's too slow and I want to optimize it. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

```js
function processData(n, a, b){
  var ans = [0];
  for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    var temp = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < ans.length; j++){
      var aa = ans[j] + a;
      if(temp.includes(aa) === false){
       temp.push(aa);
      }
      var bb = ans[j] + b;
      if(temp.includes(bb) === false){
        temp.push(bb);
      }
    }
    ans = temp;
  }
  ans.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
  return ans;
}
```

Comment: Can you give n=0 and n=2 example cases?

Comment: if `n=0` then there is nothing to do and if `n=2` then what u got after `n===1` add with `a` and `b`: `a+a+a`, `a+b+a`, `b+b+a`, `a+a+b`, `a+b+b`, `b+b+b`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: so of the results you can simplify because you can remove duplicates.

Comment: So you have a pattern going on here that can be solved with recursion.  n=1 -> 2a + (a+b) + 2b, n=2 -> 3a + (2)(2a+b) + (2)(2b + a) + 3b.  Could you provide me with n=3 also, it is difficult to work out by hand?

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Comment: Why for `n=2` you list `a+b+a` and `a+a+b`, but not `b+a+a`? I would think either all 3 of those, or just one, but two...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function processData(n, a, b) {
  var ans = [];
  if (a == b) {
    for (var i=0; i<n+1; i++) {
      ans.push(a * n);
    }
    return ans;
  } else if (a > b) {
    var temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
  }
  var diff = b - a;
  for (var i=0; i<n+1; i++) {
      ans.push(a * n + diff * i);
  }
  return ans;
}
```

Okay, this is by far the most efficient solution. I've just tested it on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1z5og9m4/5/).

All other three solutions greatly outperform yours. Mine is better than @abc123's because there's no need for sorting and better than @georg's because there's no need for using set or sorting.

Comment: this is very smart!

Comment: Great solution! A small improvement is to calculate `a*n` outside the loops, it might make a big difference for large values on a & n as it gets expensive to recalculate the product

Comment: @Gaafar That's a good catch. In fact, we can avoid multiplication altogether by adding previous element and diff to obtain next element in the array.

Answer (score 2):

This is a proposal which gets the postions for a and b.

```js
function combine(left, right) {

    function carry() {
        return c.reduceRight(function (r, _, i, o) {
            return r && !(o[i] = (o[i] + 1) % left.length);
        }, 1);
    }

    var c = Array.apply(null, { length: right.length }).map(function () { return 0; }),
        result = [];

    do {
        result.push(c.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
            r[left[a]].push(right[i]);
            return r;
        }, left.reduce(function (r, a) {
            r[a] = [];
            return r;
        }, {})));
    } while (!carry());
    return result;
}

console.log(combine(['a', 'b'], [1, 2, 3]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Just to make a disclosure, the answer is one of mine, given to a more detailed question of kind of the same, but not exactly: [Find all combinations of two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702427/find-all-combinations-of-two-arrays/31704211#31704211)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a concise ES6 function for it:

```js
function processData(n, a, b) {
    let diff = Math.abs(b-a), sum = Math.min(a,b) * (n+1) - diff;
    return diff ? Array.from(Array(n+2), _ => sum += diff) : [sum]; 
}

console.log(processData(2, 3, 5));
```

Comment: This seems to miss b+b+b = 15..   I think you just need `Array.from(Array(n+2), `  To cope with the multiple self's at start and end.

Comment: You're right, @Keith, I've updated accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

May this is faster

```
function process(a,b,n){
out=[];
//get difference
f=a-b;
var last=b*n;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
out.push(last);
last+=f;
}
return out;
}
```

Im not shure if this is right, as ive just tested with a few values. I think you wanted sth else.

Comment: Without indentation?

Answer (score 1):

### Simplified Algorithm

```js
// a+a 2 a 0 b
// a+b, b+a 1a 1b
// b+b 0a 2b

// a+a+a, 3a 0b
// a+b+a, a+a+b 2a 1b
// b+b+a, a+b+b 1a 2b
// b+b+b 0a 3b

// a+a+a+a 4a 0b
// a+a+a+b, b+a+a+a, a+a+b+a, a+b+a+a 3a 1b
// a+a+b+b, a+b+a+b, a+b+b+a, b+a+a+b, b+a+b+a, b+b+a+a 2a 2b
// a+b+b+b, b+a+b+b, b+b+a+b, b+b+b+a 1a 3b
// b+b+b+b 4b

// a+a+a+a+a 5a 0b
// a+a+a+a+b, a+a+a+b+a, a+a+b+a+a, a+b+a+a+a, b+a+a+a+a+a 4a 1b
// a+a+a+b+b, a+a+b+a+b, a+a+b+b+a, a+b+a+a+b, a+b+a+b+a, a+b+b+a+a, b+a+a+a+b, b+a+a+b+a, b+a+b+a+a, b+b+a+a+a 3a 2b
// a+a+b+b+b, a+b+a+b+b 2a 3b
// a+b+b+b+b 1a 4b
// b+b+b+b+b 0a 5b
function processData(n, a, b){
  var ans = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < n + 1; i++){
    aa = a * (n-i);
    bb = b * (i);
    ans.push(aa + bb)
  }
  ans.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
  return ans;
}

console.log(processData(3, 1, 2));
```